# Cannot access resource id from route in Laravel 5 delete request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to authorize a delete request on a resource if the resource belongs to a user for which I have created a Delete Request in Laravel 5.

For another resource I could do something like:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if(Pivot::findOrFail($this->route('pivots'))->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So basically `$this->route('pivots')` would return the id of the pivot that the user is trying to delete and I would check if it belongs to the current user.

But now I am trying for another resource similar to this one:

```
public function authorize()
{
    if(CropSection::findOrFail($this->route('crop-sections'))->pivot->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I tried to die and dump `$this->route('crop-sections')` and it comes out to be null but the request was `http://localhost:8000/crop-sections/10` which has the id as 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove dashes from the routes and/or route name?

Comment: That came to mind but I did not try it I don't know why. I'll give it a try and let you know. Unfortunately I won't be around a PC for a few hours. But thanks. I shall try it

Comment: Where does the `pivot` attribute come from? Is it a relation, or a custom accessor?

Comment: have you tried running `php artisan route:list` to see if the name of the argument is not 'crop-sections'?

Comment: @Alex : You were right. Removing the '-' hyphen solved my issue. Explain to me why and the bounty is yours. :)

Comment: @Rohan ha, just saw that it worked for you. glad it fixed it, the docs say it's not allowed to have dash for route parameters, i guess that of course means for ALL parameters, including the static ones like "/crop-sections/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change 'crop-sections' to 'crop_sections'.

Route parameters cannot contain the - character. Use an underscore (_) instead.

You can find more info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters).